# Best practices for git maintenance?

Tags: git, git-maintenance

I'm looking at the [git-maintenance](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance) manual and is unclear for me how the actual maintenance tasks are performed. To my understanding, once I execute `git maintenance run --auto`, several tasks are executed in the background. For example, if I perform a `git pull`, any related maintenance tasks should be executed automatically.

The part I cannot properly comprehend is if these tasks need to be scheduled by myself prior, or the `--auto` switch does that for me. My goal is to have the following maintenance tasks executed at specified timeline:

- gc: weekly, default disabled
- commit-graph: hourly
- prefetch: hourly
- loose-objects: daily
- incremental-repack: daily

I would like to know what are the proper `git maintenance` commands to properly schedule the above tasks and also to get your input of recommended timelines for each task, they are taken from the manual, except `gc`, which is disabled by default.

Current `./.git` structure, prior running any `git maintenance` commands:

```bash
# git --version
git version 2.30.2

# ls -lah .git
total 303K
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   13 Dec 27 17:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   19 Dec 27 17:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   21 Dec 27 17:18 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    2 Dec 27 17:17 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  252 Dec 27 17:18 config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   73 Dec 27 17:17 description
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   15 Dec 27 17:17 hooks
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 553K Dec 27 17:18 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    3 Dec 27 17:17 info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4 Dec 27 17:18 logs
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4 Dec 27 17:17 objects
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Dec 27 17:18 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    5 Dec 27 17:18 refs
```

`./git/config` `[maintenance]` section:

```
[maintenance]
    auto = false
    strategy = incremental
```

I expected running `git maintenance run --auto` command to set `auto = true`, but it is not. Thank you for taking the time to provide an example, how to properly configure the repo maintenance.

Comment: `maintenance.auto` controls whether some commands run `git maintenance run --auto` after doing their normal work. When `--auto` is combined with the `run` subcommand, run maintenance tasks only if certain thresholds are met. They cannot meet your goal.

Comment: `git maintenance` is too new to have any established Best Practices, which is just as well as "best practices" are automatically off-topic on StackOverflow.  Be aware that future releases of Git might fiddle with how these maintenance commands work, to some extent.